# JavaScript Object method not changing property

Tags: javascript, object, methods, tdd

I am building a factory function to manage Ship objects for a battleship game. So far I have the following:

```
    const Ship = (name, length, orientation = 'horizontal') => {
  let sunk = false;
  const hits = Array(length).fill(false);

  const hit = (position) => {
    if (position <= hits.length) hits[position] = true;
  };

  function sink() {
    sunk = true;
  }

  return {
    name,
    length,
    orientation,
    sunk,
    hits,
    hit,
    sink,
  };
};
```

I am testing the `sink()` method to change the sunk property boolean from `false` to `true`. However, whenever I run:

`example.sink()`
`example.sunk`
sunk always remains false.

Where am I going wrong?

For some reason the `hit()` method alters the `hits` property`fine. But`sink()`is not altering the`sunk` property.

Thanks

Comment: How did you invoke the method?

Comment: `sunk` is a boolean value, not an array ref like `hits`. The object returned by `Ship` isn't re-evaluated, so the value will always be the same.

Comment: Thanks, so how can I achieve what I am looking to do?

Comment: You can create `getter` and `setter` for `sunk` property.

Comment: @LearningPython I'd probably take a quick step back and find some good JS OOP tutorials, then decide which JS OOP approach you want to take. There are several ways this could be approached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to retrieve the values:

```js
const Ship = (name, length, orientation = 'horizontal') => {
  let sunk = false;
  const hits = Array(length).fill(false);

  const hit = position => {
    if (position <= hits.length) hits[position] = true;
  };

  function sink() {
    sunk = true;
  }

  return {
    name,
    length,
    orientation,
    hit,
    sink,
    // get values using getters
    get sunk() { return sunk; },
    get hits() { return hits; },
  };
};

const someShip = Ship(`ss something`, 100, `vertical`);
someShip.sink();
console.log(someShip.sunk);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a API method to access the local `sunk` method

```js
const Ship = (name, length, orientation = "horizontal") => {
  let sunk = false;
  const hits = Array(length).fill(false);

  const hit = (position) => {
    if (position <= hits.length) hits[position] = true;
  };

  function sink() {
    sunk = true;
  }

  function getSunk() {
    return sunk;
  }

  return {
    name,
    length,
    orientation,
    hits,
    hit,
    sink,
    getSunk,
  };
};

const ship = Ship("a", 10);
console.log(ship.getSunk());
ship.sink();
console.log(ship.getSunk());
```